# Hacking a dollar store alarm

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, hacking

Hi guys I saw these window/door alarms https://m.dollartree.com/h5/r/product/Battery-Powered-Window-Alerts/p328789/index.pro
at the dollar tree that work off of inductance I'm guessing. When the magnet bar is separated from the main unit it sounds the alarm.

When they're realigned it turns off. I'm wondering if I got one how could I delay the alarm so if the bar magnet and unit are aligned it keeps sounding for a given amount of time (10-30 seconds)

Comment: Fit them with an almost-dead battery. Or you could give use the _schematic_ to this product. How are we supposed to know when you don't even have one?

Comment: I couldn't find one online

Comment: Still you expect the users here to use their expensive xray vision on the image in the link you posted, to see through the packaging and the case how it's constructed.

Comment: Rip it apart. Find the alarm activating signal. Disconnect it from the alarm. Connect to delay circuit input. Connect the alarm to the delay circuit output.

Comment: @pipe Maybe someone else has done what I'm asking how would I know without posting?

Comment: Welcome on EE.SE. Please, keep in mind that this is not a general electronics forum. The goal of the community is to build a high quality knowledge base in Q&A form, therefore we ask any contributor to format her/his post in a way that benefits the whole community. As it stands your question is not helping the community in any way, since it is not answerable. Moreover it doesn't show any effort. Please, see the [help] to learn how to ask here.

Comment: I imagine that *regardless* of the schematic for the alarm, the same general theory applies. Simply break the path to the output of the alarm, and insert a timer of sorts in series. Or, insert a timer of sorts in parallel with the sensor path (Perhaps a simple capacitor would do here?)

Comment: It uses a simple magnetic reed switch to sense the magnet being moved.

Answer (score 1):

It uses a magnetic reed switch. Check to see if it triggers open or closed. And if it's active high or active low. Remove reed switch. Put a timer/delay circuit like a 555/556 timer in its place. Use the reed switch to trigger the 556 circuit. The circuit could be configured to always trigger on removal, but stay on for n seconds after released. Google 556 delay circuits.

Since it's battery powered, you want a newer type of low power 555 circuit, with an Iq of microamps, not milliamps. The needed parts for these may not fit inside the alarm.

See https://youtu.be/UvKLp_sZ0H0 for an example of it opened and hacked.

Depending in how the switch works, you could try an RC delay. Which could introduce a delay in both turning on and turning off the alarm.

Comment: Thank you. Think an addition of a resistor/capacitor could create a delay?

Comment: A cap maybe, but unless you add a huge battery draining one, it won't be a long delay. Depends on how it's actually wired.